# Disable Registry redirect

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, registry

i'm use this code for add registry file to registry but in windows 64 bit this value

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\

inserted to under wow6432node

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer

how can I avoid it?

```
Process regeditProcess = Process.Start("regedit.exe", "nero10.reg"); 
                regeditProcess.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: That is the right node to insert to in Win 64 bit.

Comment: but if starting the .reg file is inserted in the right place because use the application goes under wow64?

Comment: @John let's not pick on new users for not knowing the ropes as perfectly as us. I've been here for a year and didn't realize that. This guys question shows more time and effort than over half of the other new user questions.

Comment: @rlb: how is it picking on someone to tell them  how we do things here? How else will they "learn the ropes"?